# how to train a bert model from scratch with huggingface?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, fine-tuning

i find a answer of training model from scratch in this question:
[How to train BERT from scratch on a new domain for both MLM and NSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646925/how-to-train-bert-from-scratch-on-a-new-domain-for-both-mlm-and-nsp)

one answer use Trainer and TrainingArguments like this:

```
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir= "/path/to/output/dir/for/training/arguments"
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_gpu_train_batch_size= 16,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset,
)

trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("path/to/your/model")
```

but huggingface official doc [Fine-tuning a pretrained model](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html)
 also use Trainer and TrainingArguments in the same way to finetune .
so when I use Trainer and TrainingArguments to train model, Do I train model from scratch or just finetune?

Comment: Depends on what you set as `model`. Maybe you ant to follow this [blog post]9https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train).

Comment: From the code that you posted, and the code in the link you provided, I think that code is for fine-tuning a model.

Comment: @cronoik    I have seen the blog,but it only describe how to use a script like run_language_modeling.py instead of using Trainer.if you explain more details about"Depends on what you set as model",it will be helpful。

Comment: The `run_language_modeling` script is also using the trainer. The difference between finetuning and pretraining is not that you do something specific with your trainer (maybe you will adjust the learning rate). The difference is that you randomly initialize your weights or load some weights and train them for an objective that is not your final task (pretraining) OR that you train a model for a down stream task (e.g. sentiment analysis) that you want to solve (finetuning) .

Comment: I have the same question, I am really lose reading their doc

Answer (score 3):

Hey first of all thank you for linking my question, I will do my best to clarify it :)

First of all there is no big difference between pre-training & fine-tuning. The only difference is in pre-training you train your model from scratch, in order words you initialized the weights by initial value (it can be random or zero) however in fine-tuning you actually load a pre-trained model and then train it again for a downstream task, so basically what you are doing is initializing weights by pre-trained model. Therefore you can use the knowledge that is captured by the pre-trained model.

Lets try to understand fine-tuning and pre-training architecture.
In the following diagram shows us the overview of pre-training architecture.

[image]

When you fine-tune BERT model you change that task specific area and labels. When you change task specific area, you change the overall architecture. You replace the heads. Also this change has affected the naming of model that you are using in Transformers. For example BertForPreTraining uses both MLM and NSP head at the same time, whereas BertForSequenceClassification uses a linear layer as a head just like in NSP. But what they have in common is that they wrap BERT model. So we just change "task specific" area (architecture). This is what they meant by stating "There is minimal difference between the pre-trained architecture and the final downstream architecture." in [BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805).

If you want to change BERT's pre-training task, you must change the architecture of task specific area and input labels just like I did in "[Same Sentence Prediction: A new Pre-training Task for BERT](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9598954)"([Github Repo](https://github.com/kaansonmezoz/bert-same-sentence-prediction)). Same goes for the fine-tuning process. If you want to customize fine-tuning architecture for a downstream task, all you need to do this changing the architecture of task specific area.

So it doesn't matter using Trainer for pre-training or fine-tuning. Trainer will basically updates the weights of model according to training loss. If you use pre-trained BERT with downstream task specific heads, it will update weights in both BERT model and task specific heads (unless you tell it otherwise by freezing the weights of BERT model). If you use untrained BERT model with task specific heads it will also update weights.